# How to use `cat` or `less` depending on the line count?

Tags: less, cat

When looking at the content of files, I'd like to automatically `cat` short files but `less` those that exceed the screen size. I could use something with `wc -l`, but is there a better way that maybe also considers the window size / current amount of lines available?

Comment: While many tools do this, note that it breaks expectability. I.e. the user cannot known in advance what will happen. I find this annoying for instance in `git log` which does this exact thing. You never know in advance what you're going to get (do you have to hit `q`?).

Comment: NOTE: In general you should avoid using `cat` to view files. Typically you should only use `cat` to send the contents of a file to stdout so it can be piped to another process. The reason to avoid using `cat` for viewing is that it sends the raw bytes to the terminal, which can cause unexpected terminal commands to be executed (e.g., some users have gotten stuck when a file happened to contain the right bytes to disable the terminal keyboard). You should usually use a pager like `less` or an editor, which will format special characters for display so they aren't interpreted by the terminal.

Comment: If you're going to use cat to view file contents directly in the terminal, at least use `cat -v` so it escapes special characters.

Comment: @bitmask good point, that's why I asked [Is split-screen `cat`ing possible?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41370/is-split-screen-cating-possible) which might be a better solution

Comment: @ChrisPage My keyboard wasn't killed, but I think I managed to screw up the codepage once... Thanks for pointing `cat -v` out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To give you the formula which involves the `wc`-based check:

```
(($(wc -l<input_file)<=$(tput lines))) && echo 'will fit' || echo 'not enough'
```

There is a `$LINES` shell variable which can also be used:

```
(($(wc -l<input_file)<=LINES)) && echo 'will fit' || echo 'not enough'
```

But `$LINES` is updated only when at the command prompt. To understand what I mean, run this and resize the terminal window during the `sleep`:

```
( sleep 3; echo $LINES; tput lines )
```

Comment: Thanks, this has the advantage that it can be tuned to use `less` already if e.g. 2/3 of the screen were used by `cat`.

Answer (score 20):

Maybe 'less -F file_to_read' is the option : it exits less if the window is sufficient to display all the file, and wait on the pager if it is not the case

Comment: sounds good, but that does not output anything in that case, and the exit codes is the same in both cases

Comment: I just try 'less -F /etc/passwd' and it display the file correctely (with or without pager). You are right, the return code is 0 in both cases.

Comment: That command works as requested, but with a minor glitch: it clears the screen after displaying the file. Adding the `-X` option will stop the clearing, so short files will be displayed like `cat` does. Unfortunately with `-X` the screen will not be cleared neither after displaying long, scrolled files.

Comment: @manatwork that's great, thanks. Not clearing the screen is actually ok, since that's what would (not) happen if `cat` were called as well