# Is split-screen `cat`ing possible?

Tags: bash, terminal

I asked the question [How to use `cat` or `less` depending on the line count?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41358/how-to-use-cat-or-less-depending-on-the-line-count) with the intention of browsing many files without having to scroll up too far to view my history after displaying a long file, while keeping short files' contents directly visible.

However, it would be even more convenient to simply use half the screen for "usual" bash output and the other half (right or top, probably a matter of taste) for `cat` output. Is there a nice way (maybe some `screen`-magic) to achieve this? I.e. have a splitscreen terminal, where a simple pipe relocates output to the other half, and maybe some second pair of hotkeys to separately scroll through that half's buffer?

My first impulse would be using `mkfifo` for the pipe, but maybe there's an easier way or someone actually already wrote a tool for this...

Comment: I use tmux and if i do - :pipe-page -o "cat >> /tmp/foo" i can see all content of the "windows" in the file. So if i split tmux and i would to tail -f /tmp/foo i would see the output of a "window" redirected to pipe.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but probably does what you want: [Linux - How to split the terminal into more than one "view"?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7453)

Answer (score 4):

You can redirect `cat` output without any fifo and pipes to:

1. `/dev/pts/NUM` where NUM is number of your logged in pts. it may not
   be usefull in screen splitting)
2. `/proc/PID/fd/0` (where PID is PID of your shell process in terminal, where output should appear).

Comment: thanks, now I just have to figure out how to use `screen` (or other means) to split the screen...

Comment: Ctrl+a | for vertical split
Ctrl+a S for horizontal split
Ctrl+a <tab> to switch